# DS_Store file is created on ZipArchive::extractTo

Tags: php, zip, unzip, php-ziparchive

I'm creating a PHP script, which supposed to extract a zip archive stored on the php file directory to a folder.
Everything works well, but when I check te result, I find 2 folders under the directory: a folder with the name of the zip archive, and another folder named `__MACOSX`. I don't know how this folder came there, especially as I'm using Windows 7. Second, in each folder there is a file called `.DS_Store`.
Now, I don't know how these things got there. This is my code:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('File.zip')) {
    $path = getcwd() . "/details/" . trim($id) . "/";
    $path = str_replace("\\","/",$path);
    echo $path;
    echo $zip->extractTo($path);
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

This is the only code that extracts the zip file, or touching it, and as you can see, there is nothing like `__MACOSX` or `.DS_Store`.

Can you please help me?

Comment: Don't worry, the .DS_store is the file that macOS create to remember how to display the folder (like how to rearrange every file), you can remove it 

Comment: @ArthurGuiot But I'm using Windows. And what about that folder being created?

Comment: The files are in the archive and they were extracted from it. Most probably the archive was created on an macOS system. These files are hidden on macOS and many users include them in the archives they create without even knowing. `.DS_Store` is, more or less, the equivalent of `Thumbs.db` generated by Windows Explorer.

Comment: @axiac A closer equivalent is `Desktop.ini`. `.DS_Store` is used to store Finder window settings, e.g. window size/position, "view as" mode, icon locations…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.zip` originated on a OSX system. `__MACOSX` and `.DS_Store` have 0 usage or bearing on any other OS. Delete / Ignore them and keep trucking.

As an aside, you may want to add the stated file system objects to your project .gitignore.

https://superuser.com/questions/104500/what-is-macosx-folder
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store